# Xcode takes too long to open a project

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to open a project in Xcode it takes too much time to open.

Xcode stop responding and after a long time, it then opens.

I’m running a MacBook Pro 2017 16gb, i7. I was facing this issue in my old MacBook Pro 2015 8Gb, i5 and that was the main reason why I upgrade it. I made a backup from the old Mac to the new one, so I don’t know if it’s related but it’s still the same. Also, I tried creating a new user and moving all my folders there and it’s still the same. I don’t really know what else to do.

Edit.
I already tried deleting temp file folders and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Does the "pizza of death" spin during the delay?

Comment: Oh, one more thought: is this a competely clean fresh installation of the system and Xcode, or did you move / copy your hard drive from the old machine to the new one?

Comment: Do you have an SSD or an HD?

Comment: @matt I used the migration assistant to move all my data from my old MacBook to the new one.

Comment: @El tomato it’s an 500Gb SSD

Comment: @LeonardoEmilioDominguez See, that's a worry. Maybe there's something else in there that got brought across and is slowing things down. You had a problem and you _brought it with you_. I suggest, if there's room, that you make a new _partition_ (doesn't have to be huge, 70 GB will do), install a totally clean system into it, install Xcode there, and play with it there. If Xcode is fast there, then something is going on with the remnants of your old system. I also suggest that this is effectively an AskDifferent or SuperUser question at this point, not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I now remember one condition that happened to have slowed my work in Xcode several years ago.  Opening Preferences and navigating to Source Control, if you turn on the Enable Source Control checkbox, it can dramatically slow your work.

Comment: Have you tried selecting Product > Clean Build Folder?